# Add custom data for each day in ion-datetime

Tags: datetime, ionic-framework, mobile, datetimepicker, ionic-native

I want to add custom data in each calendar day like Google Flights does and cannot find anything about it. Adding below each calendar day a custom text describing something.

I tried to use a third party libraries but I don't like them. I want to use all the same components for my app as far as possible. I am using the components by **Ionic 7 ** by the way. It should looks like Google Flight calendar when you check flights in the calendar widget (screenshot attached)

If this is not possible, recommend me good alternatives I will appreciate that.

Thank you so much.

[image]